# using the _was method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i am trying to use the _was method on an attribute.
Lets say i have an object `Person`:

```
Person.name = "new name"

Person.name_was = "old name"
```

if i were to call `Person.changed?` it would return `["name"]`.

So my question is: can i somehow use the values from `person.changed` to do something like this:

```
Person.changed.each do |x|
  Person.x => returns undefined value for x
  Person['x'] => returns new name
  Person["#{'x'}_was"] => errors
end
```

Is there a way I can use the `_was` method with the string variable from `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the example code is trying to achieve, but I think you are looking for the #changes method;

```
person = Person.create(first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', sex: 'Male')
person.first_name = 'Jane'
person.sex = 'Female'
person.changes.each do |attribute, change|
  puts attribute
  puts change.first
  puts change.last
end

# => 'first_name'
# => 'John'
# => 'Jane'
# => 'sex'
# => 'Male'
# => 'Female'
```

person.changes returns a hash with all the changes where;
{ attribute_name => [before, after] }

Answer (score 0):

if you have the name of the attribute in a variable, you can use `send`. Also, `Person` is probably a class, and I guess you're rather working with an instance. Try with:

```
person = Person.first

# stuff happens...

person.changed.each do |x|
  person.public_send(x)
  person.public_send("#{x}_was")
end
```

Or don't reinvent the wheel and just use `person.changes`. Have a look at the [`ActiveModel::Dirty` module](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'public_send' or 'method' method

```
person = Person.first

person.name # => 'Jhon Doe'
person.gender # => 'M'
person.birthdate # => Wed, 05 Sep 1984

person.name = 'Jane Doe'
person.gender = 'F'

person.changed.each do |attr|
  p person.public_send(attr) # => person.name => 'Jane Doe'
  p person.method(attr).call      # => person.name => 'Jane Doe'
  p person.public_send("#{attr}_was") # => person.name_was => 'Jhon Doe'
  p person.method("#{attr}_was").call      # => person.name_was => 'Jhon Doe'
end
```

but `_was` attributes are getters and no have setters.

Comment: This won't work: `person.method(attr)`, because it will just return an object representing the method. To actually _invoke_ the method, you need to send to it the `call` message: `p person.method(attr).call`.